# Generating Getters/Setters with AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

I want to write an aspect that will generate getters/setters for the fields of a class where it is being used.

I am a beginner to AspectJ, can someone point me in the right direction? A sample would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/). It generates getters/setters and various other handy methods. It integrates with Eclipse so technically non-existing accessors are visible.

Comment: This is almost what I need, but I would need to add the `@Getter` and `@Setter` dynamically, would that be possible with AspectJ?

Comment: Project Lombok works at compile time. Adding the annotations dynamically will not resolve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) which generates getters and setters by generating AspectJ ITDs.

Not the most elegant thing but it gets the job done with out the runtime cost of other things like lambok.

Comment: Lombok doesn't have runtime overhead.

Answer (score 0):

(not fully sure but...) I'm affraid that aspect programming can add behaviour to classes, not interface. If you could generate getters/setters in runtime... anyway you coudn't call them in your code because they wouldn't exist yet. You'd have a compile-time error.

Maybe you could use some IDE source generator. As in Eclipse: Source menu -> generate getters/setters.

Comment: Actually, with ITD you can add behaviour to interfaces and abstract classes as well, as they will act as Mixins. You still woudn't be able to instantiate interfaces, but every class implementing it will have the behaviour added to the interfaces.